# html data-filter set on other page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, attributes

I have a page where a user can filter for different products. This works so far.

```
                <ul class="nav__list" width="100px" id="filters">
                    <li>
                        <li><button data-filter="*">All Products</button></li>
                        <li><button data-filter=".categorie1">Product1</button></li>
                        <li><button data-filter=".categorie1">Product2</button></li>
                        <li><button data-filter=".categorie2">Product2</button></li>
                        <li><button data-filter=".categorie2">Product3</button></li>
                        <li><button data-filter=".categorie3">Product4</button></li>
                    </li>
                  <ul>
```

Is there a possibility to call a filter for e.g. categorie2 from a different page? Something like the link below would be awesome:

```
<a href="shop.php?filter=categorie2">Categorie2</a>
```

Any ideas if this is possible?

Many thanks

Comment: What Javascript libraries are you using? You could grab the url param and fire your filter functions, but we'll need to see some JS to help out further.

Comment: These libaries are used:
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

But I don't know where the data-filter function is included :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are missing a `<ul>` after your first `<li>`
From the question I don't fully understand what you want to do.

Do you want to sort the items on the page?

Do you want to reload some items and then filter them?

Do you want send a filter request to the server?

```
<ul class="nav__list" width="100px" id="filters">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><button data-filter="*">All Products</button></li>
            <li><button data-filter=".categorie1">Product1</button></li>
            <li><button data-filter=".categorie1">Product2</button></li>
            <li><button data-filter=".categorie2">Product2</button></li>
            <li><button data-filter=".categorie2">Product3</button></li>
            <li><button data-filter=".categorie3">Product4</button></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: I want a function like here: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/Ehgij the sorting on my shop page already works. What I want to have is a third page where the user can directly click on a category and then will be redirected to the shop page filter by the category

Comment: Well you always have access to the url with location.pathname. So you can wait after the page loads and then set the filter if it is in the url.

Comment: With var selected_filter = window.location.search.substring(8); I'm getting the raw filter name like categorie2 from the url. But how do I set the data filter automatically at page load?

Comment: You can programmaticly click the button?

Answer (score 0):

I can get the query string using `window.location.search`

Now you can use JavaScript to call the function used to filter the products using the same query string.

Comment: It will be better if you use `select` in place of `ul`